# How to view constructor properties of a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

for example, I create a constructor function called `Test`,

```
         function Test(a,b)
         {
               this.a = a;
               this.b = b;
               var test = "test";
         }
```

When I attempt to view the properties of the `Test` constructor in firefox debug mode, I don't see these properties (`a`, `b`, and `test`) I define. Why?

[image: constructor Test]

Comment: The constructor is just an ordinary function. The properties are in the objects that you create with it.

Comment: True, I did see the properties through the object but how can I view them from the constructor function?

Comment: You can't, they're not part of the constructor function. The constructor function just executes that as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `b` are not properties of the constructor. When you create an object using the constructor, the object will get those properties as a result of the assignments. But as far as the constructor itself is concerned, those are just ordinary lines of code, there's nothing special that makes them act as properties.

```
var t = new Test(1, 2);
```

If you view `t` you will see the `a` and `b` properties.

`test` is not a property at all, it's just a local variable inside the constructor. The only way to see it is to set a breakpiont in the constructor and examine the local variables. Variables are not part of a `Function` object.